# Ubuntu crashes randomly xorg

Tags: xorg, crash

I'm not an expert in Ubuntu, so I have no idea how to solve this issue. My Ubuntu 20.04 crashes randomly and sends me to the login screen.
I don't know where to look up at error files, but I've found this var/crash/_usr_lib_xorg_Xorg.1000.crash file, which header says the following:

```
ProblemType: Crash
Architecture: amd64
CrashCounter: 1
CurrentDesktop: ubuntu:GNOME
Date: Wed Mar 23 17:15:15 2022
DistroRelease: Ubuntu 20.04
ExecutablePath: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg
ExecutableTimestamp: 1639491253
ProcCmdline: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg vt2 -displayfd 3 -auth /run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority -background none -noreset -keeptty -verbose 3
ProcCwd: /home/tidop
ProcEnviron:
 PATH=(custom, no user)
 XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=<set>
 LANG=es_ES.UTF-8
 SHELL=/bin/bash
ProcMaps:
 55742c038000-55742c075000 r--p 00000000 08:12 12976830                   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg
 55742c075000-55742c207000 r-xp 0003d000 08:12 12976830                   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg
 55742c207000-55742c280000 r--p 001cf000 08:12 12976830                   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg
 55742c280000-55742c284000 r--p 00247000 08:12 12976830                   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg
 55742c284000-55742c28f000 rw-p 0024b000 08:12 12976830                   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg
 55742c28f000-55742c2cd000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
 55742d4a5000-557439da6000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [heap]
 7fe3c0000000-7fe3c0021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
 7fe3c0021000-7fe3c4000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
 7fe3c4000000-7fe3c4021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
 7fe3c4021000-7fe3c8000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
```

I will show any file if someone tells me where to find it.
I think this error started after I tried to install adobe reader, but I'm not totally sure about it. These were the lines I run at terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install gtk2-engines-murrine:i386 libcanberra-gtk-module:i386 libatk-adaptor:i386 libgail-common:i386

sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ precise partner"
 
sudo apt-get update
 
sudo apt-get install adobereader-enu

sudo gedit /etc/gnome/defaults.list

nautilus -q
```

Don't know if this can help... I also removed adobereader-enu later.

I would really appreciate any help, cause this is my work pc and I'm scared I have broken it...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try apt remove adobereader-enu after this run
apt autoremove --purge and then
Reboot laptop.
If error persist check logs with journalctl -xe and search for errors inside log.

Comment: Hello. I am at a loss to see how you arrived at this as an answer. No where in the question does the OP mention adobereader-enu So how does removing a program it seems they do not have help?

Comment: I've tried this, but I think it has not work.